# Custom Author (Year, pages) citation with hyperlink functionality

Tags: formatting, citing

I am trying to create a custom citation command that displays as Author (Year, pages) while hyperlinking if the URL field is defined. However, I have run into an issue where any conditional logic placed inside the citational will be printed after the citation, i.e. the page numbering will always be placed after the year brackets, despite being called within them.

This is my current minimum example:

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true, backend=biber, style=authoryear, giveninits=true, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring} % For string comparison/checks

% prints page numbers
\newcommand{\printpages}[1]{%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {} % Return blank if input is empty
    {\StrCount{#1}{-}[\rangecount]% Count dashes to infer if it's a range
     \ifthenelse{\rangecount > 0}
       {pp.~#1} % Multiple pages
       {p.~#1}% Single page
    }%
}

% cite command
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeurlya}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{url}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \printfield{year}%
         \printpages{#1}%
       }}
      {\href{\thefield{url}}{%
         \printtext[parens]{%
           \printfield{year}%
           \printpages{#1}%
         }}%
      }%
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{example2021,
  author    = {Author, A.},
  title     = {An Example Article},
  journal   = {Journal of Examples},
  year      = {2021},
  url       = {https://example.com/article},
}

@article{example2022,
  author    = {Buthor, B.},
  title     = {An Example Article},
  journal   = {Journal of Examples},
  year      = {2021},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
See \citeurlya[123]{example2021} for a specific detail and \citeurlya[124--125]{example2021} for an extended discussion. \citeurlya[3, 6]{example2022} is also good.
\printbibliography

\end{document} ```

the output is: See Author (2021), p. 123 for a specific detail and Author (2021), pp. 124–
125 for an extended discussion. Buthor (2021), pp. 3, 6 is also good
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it. I needed to close the parentheses after the postnote macro. These commands will print (author, year, pages) and author (year, pages). hyperlinking the author to the article if provided and hyperlinking the year to the bibliography entry:

```
% Helper command to decide between "p." and "pp."
\newbibmacro{print:pages}[1]{%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {} % Return blank if input is empty
    {\StrCount{#1}{-}[\rangecount]% Count dashes to infer if it's a range
     \ifthenelse{\rangecount > 0}
       {, pp.~#1} % Multiple pages
       {, p.~#1}% Single page
    }%
}

% Command for (authors year) format
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeurl}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {%
    \iffieldundef{url}
      {\printnames{labelname}} % Just print the names if no URL is available
      {\href{\thefield{url}}{\printnames{labelname}}} % Make the names a hyperlink
    \addcomma\addspace
      \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
    \usebibmacro{print:pages}{#1}% Print pages if provided
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% Command for Author (year) format
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeurltext}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {%
    \iffieldundef{url}
      {\printnames{labelname}} % Just print the names if no URL is available
      {\href{\thefield{url}}{\printnames{labelname}}} % Make the names a hyperlink
    \addspace
     \bibopenparen\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}\usebibmacro{print:pages}{#1}%
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}\bibcloseparen}
```